# How to delete text with a backspace using `nvi` on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, vi, nvi

For some reason, it’s impossible to backspace delete text that is already present in the file before the current insert mode switch.

If I try to edit a line in this text and then backspace it in the insert mode, I can only be able to delete the newly added letters by hitting `esc` right after `backspace`.
But it won't delete already present letters. The caret just stops before them.

`nvi` does not support `:set backspace` either.

In short, my task is to delete some letters to the left from the middle of a word in the present text using backspace in `nvi`.
How to achieve this?

Comment: @Quasímodo I would ask the similar question. Why do they include `nvi` into FreeBSD if it is useless?

Answer (score 1):

This is how `nvi` behaves. To alter `nvi` you will need to patch the source code, probably to comment out [the following block](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/contrib/nvi/vi/v_txt.c#n992) in `v_txt.c`, and recompile:

```
    /* If nothing to erase, bell the user. */
    if (tp->cno <= tp->offset) {
        if (!LF_ISSET(TXT_REPLAY))
            txt_nomorech(sp);
        break;
    }
```

Or, again, you could install `vim` if you want `vim` features.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand why they did not include this option in their codebase.  That's strange that such a trivial thing is not possible in this editor. I want to understand how to use common features in `nvi` not `vim`.

Comment: Many such trivial things were added to `vim`. You can fork `nvi` and start adding new features, if you want. Otherwise, the BSD base `nvi` is refreshingly simple and will hopefully remain that way, especially given the ready availability of alternatives in the ports system.